# JavaScript Comment Node and parsing the HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working with Nodes and  comments in html. Is  there a way without any plugin to parse the HTML inside of a comment?

I can currently use  the  nodeValue method but that only returns a string.

Even  getting attributes in a element inside a comment would be helpful.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using nodeValue is good to go. Please review this one:

```js
function log(str) {
  document.body.innerHTML += str + '<br>';
}

var x = Array.from(document.body.childNodes);

x.forEach(function(el) {
  if (el.nodeType === 8) {
    var div, elm;
    div = document.createElement('div');
    log(el.nodeValue);
    div.innerHTML = el.nodeValue;
    
    //here we get element we need
    elm = div.children[0];
    console.log(elm.nodeName, "id = " + elm.getAttribute('id'));
  }
})
```

```html
<!--
<select id="testid">
<option value="1">text1</option>
<option value="2">text2</option>
<option value="3">text3</option>
</select>
-->
```

Comment: Thanks! Going to try this tonight!

Answer (score 0):

You can do regex matching on the comment content (the string). Even one more option : put a valid JSON string in the comment, and later turn it into a valid JS object using `JSON.parse()`.